# Extract any word in comma delimited string

Tags: javascript

```
var str = "dog,cat,rat,bat";
pos = str.indexOf( ',' );
var res= str.substring( 0, pos );
```

But that only gets me the first word. I want the ability to get any word in a string on unknown length.

Comment: Use `split`, then you can access by index.

Comment: do you want to get an array of words such as ["dog","cat" ...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `.split()` method to split a string into an array.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

```
var str = "dog,cat,rat,bat";
var parts = str.split(',');
alert(parts[2]); // rat
```

Comment: What if I dont know the index ? Example , I want to read rat. It might occur in different positions ?

Answer (score 3):

```
var str = "dog,cat,rat,bat"; 
var strArray = str.split(",");
```

This will create an array of values. You can pass any delimiter into `split()`.

You can `join()` to put them back together.

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = "dog,cat,rat,bat";
// use split to transform the string into an array
str = str.split(',');

var res = str[0]; // 1, 2, 3...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
console.log(str.split(","));
```

Comment: Why should the OP try that?

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "dog,cat,rat,bat";
var array1=[];
array1=str.split(',');
for(var key in array1){
    console.log(array1[key]);
}
```

it will return all word in str variable

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "dog,cat,rat,bat";
var res = str.split(",");
```

The result is an array with "dog" "cat" "rat" and "bat" element